# How to retrieve uOpen data in Google script with returned JSON array?

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am using Google Script to get an JSON data - see below the data. But I can't retrieve the specific value in that JSON data using typical node method. How can I get the specific field in the JSON data I got?

I use Google Script to get stock data:

```
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/tsla/chart/date/20190911?chartByDay=true&token=myToken");
var content = res.getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(content);
```

The  `Logger.log` shows `json` as below:

```
[{date=2019-09-11, uHigh=248.17, uVolume=10042777, change=11.56, uOpen=237.38, uLow=236, uClose=247.1, label=Sep 11, volume=10042777, high=248.17, low=236, changeOverTime=0.049079, changePercent=4.9079, close=247.1, open=237.38}]
```

Then I tried to `Logger.log (json.uOpen)` but it returns `undefined` object. Any help would be highly appreciated!

I expect to get the uOpen data: 237.78

Comment: What does log(content) show?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is an array so you have to indicate the position in the array so json[0]. Code looks like :

```
function getData(){
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/tsla/chart/date/20190911?chartByDay=true&token=myToken");
  var content = res.getContentText();
  Logger.log(content)
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  /*
  [{date=2019-09-11, uHigh=248.17, uVolume=10042777, change=11.56, uOpen=237.38, uLow=236, uClose=247.1, 
  label=Sep 11, volume=10042777, high=248.17, low=236, changeOverTime=0.049079, changePercent=4.9079, close=247.1, open=237.38}]
  */
  Logger.log (json[0].uOpen)
}
```

Stéphane